# Kubernetes remove addons added by running deployAddons.sh on Ubuntu

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard, add-on, endpoints

I've finished installing Kubernetes on local Ubuntu cluster. After the installation i've run deployAddons.sh but the dashboard is still not working.
I get the following error:

```
no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"
```

Can you please tell me how could i rollback deployAddons.sh or how can i fix this error. I see there is some endpoints problem but i don't know where to configure those.

10x

Answer (score 0):

"No endpoints available" means that the pods for the dashboard are not running in your cluster. You should be able to check on the status of the dashboard deployment to see why they aren't running:

`kubectl describe deployment kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system`